# I want different control types in the same column of a DataGridView Windows form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();    
dt.Columns.Add("name");    
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)    
{    
    dt.Rows.Add("");    
}

this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;    
this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 200; 

DataGridViewComboBoxCell ComboBoxCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

ComboBoxCell.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "aaa","bbb","ccc" });

this.dataGridView1[0, 0] = ComboBoxCell;   
this.dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = "bbb";     

DataGridViewTextBoxCell TextBoxCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();    
this.dataGridView1[0, 1] = TextBoxCell;    
this.dataGridView1[0, 1].Value = "some text";

DataGridViewCheckBoxCell CheckBoxCell = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();    
CheckBoxCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

this.dataGridView1[0, 2] = CheckBoxCell;    
this.dataGridView1[0, 2].Value = true;
```

Got the code from : [how to host different controls in the same column in DataGridView control](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/63ddb457-f769-44db-87cc-9e88e74929e8/how-to-host-different-controls-in-the-same-column-in-datagridview-control?forum=winformsdesigner)

The grid shows up and the assigned values are in it, but when I click on the cells, the expected controls don't show up.  Can anybody figure out what is wrong?

Comment: This code works perfectly and the controls show up without clicking them. Where did you put the code? And what happened after?

Comment: Code is in the constructor.The controls don't show up

Comment: It seems to work when the code is placed in Form Load but i have data being passed to the constructor. Any Solution?

Comment: @GopinathShetty Dont put these codes in `Constructor`. Create a separate method and call that method in `Form_Load`.

Comment: Contructor is often too early. Stuff passed into the contructor should be put into class level variables.